# Does MariaDB 10 support sym files on Wndows

Tags: java, windows, mariadb

I'm working with an old Java app that's currently using MySQL 5. The app creates [schema name].sym files for each schema it creates in order to instruct MySQL to create the physical table files to the folder stated in the sym file.

With my initial tests with MariaDB 10 it seems to ignore the sym files and the schema's are created under the folder specified by the MariaDB's datadir variable, which I reckon is the typical location for the schemas to reside.

Nevertheless I tried to find info on using sym files or them being made unsupported from MariaDB documentation with no luck which made me to wonder whether the feature has been dropped out at some point between MySQL 5.0 and MariaDB 10 releases.

Can anyone tell is there still a way to make sym files (and I do **not** mean symbolic links) work with MariaDB 10 on Windows?

Answer (score 0):

For MySQL the .sym files support have been removed since MySQL 5.7.0: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/relnotes/mysql/5.7/en/news-5-7-0.html

For MariaDB at least until MariaDB 10.0 there should be .sym files support as MariaDB 10.0 is compatible with MySQL 5.6.